What does the recipient see if recall Outlook email fails?
If you and the recipient are on the same Exchange server and you recall an email you sent but the recall fails, what do they see?
Ideally, I'd want them to see nothing. But it sounds like maybe they get a request to recall the email.

Here's how email recall works when you are on the same exchange server.
You send out the email.
The other person receives the email.
You then want to recall the email. Depending on what the other person has done or will do, the outcome varies.

They have not opened the mail, and its marked as unread
The email is automatically deleted, you receive an email: recall succesful.

They have opened the mail and accepted
They will now receive a new email that tells them that you wanted to recall the email. They get the option to comply or decline. They comply, which deletes the email and sends the recall successful email to you, and the recall email itself also gets deleted.

They have opened the mail and declined
They will now receive a new email that tells them that you wanted to recall the email. They get the option to comply or decline. They decline, which deletes the recall email and sends you an email that the recall failed.


Recalling externally sent emails
When emailing to an external address that is also an exchange server, the first option is always skipped, but the second and third option still work.
When emailing to an external address that is not an exchange server, you always get a failed message back after the system confirmed that it was not an exchange server.
Footnote
So it basically matters when you recall if they see an email message or not. The quicker you send that recall, the more chance you have that they don't know. Also, if you send the email after hours, and they don't work, the chance is bigger that they don't see it, unless they also have their email on their phone and read it that way.
In either case, do it as quickly as possible, but you don't always know if they've seen it. but if the retract was successful, then at least they agreed upon your action to recall it.

Email recall is an Outlook client feature, it requires that both sender and recipient are using Exchange account in the same organization. You can only recall the emails sent to internal recipient. If you recall the message sent to external recipient, he will receive a recall notification email and the original email won’t be deleted.
Message Recall will not be successful if:

The recipient is not using Outlook.
The recipient is not logged on to the mail service provider.
The message has been moved from the Inbox.
The message has been read. This includes viewing the message with the Preview Pane so that the message is flagged as Read.

You can refer to: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/delete-particular-mail-from-all-users-through/9df5b4db-ade1-4f30-b9ff-49145cb4dd35
